# Exception when trying browser navigate into value selected in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem when trying to navigate my browser component into my combobox selected value - when the combobox value is changed.

It works fine when I'm doing it like below (but then it isnt fired when combobox2 is changed):

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sites.paths[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);

        List<Foo> combo2data = new List<Foo>();

        foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            Foo fileInsert = new Foo();
            fileInsert.path = s;
            fileInsert.name = Path.GetFileName(s);
            combo2data.Add(fileInsert);
        }

        comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data;
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "path";
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";         

        this.webBrowser1.Navigate((string)comboBox2.SelectedValue); // THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE : )
    }
```

But I see an exception (Unable to cast object of type App1.Foo to type System.String), when It's like that:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sites.paths[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);

        List<Foo> combo2data = new List<Foo>();

        foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            Foo fileInsert = new Foo();
            fileInsert.path = s;
            fileInsert.name = Path.GetFileName(s);
            combo2data.Add(fileInsert);
        }

        comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data;
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "path";
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.webBrowser1.Navigate((string)comboBox2.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: Try SelectedText instead of SelectedValue.

Comment: my selected text is "file.txt", and value is path to the file : ) So it has to be value

Comment: The you should cast it to the type that is in the value and call the ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add something like file:/// infront of your path

but there is more you should consider

Links to local files on pages that were retrieved via HTTP(S) are deliberately disabled in Mozilla/Firefox, because they can be a security risk, and have been used in attacks in the past.

[http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:*Issues*:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_Issues_%3a_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)

Comment: Nope : ) It's working in the first case - and I don't adding nothing in front of my  path. The problem appears only when it's in another function.

Comment: but it's desktop app - and it's c# webbrowser component - that's not firefox and any other browser : ]

Answer (score 0):

try changing the order of the lines from this:

```
    comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data; 
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "path"; 
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
```

To this:

```
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "path";
    comboBox2.DataSource = combo2data;
```

Then your code:

```
  (string)comboBox2.SelectedValue
```

will give the correct result which is the value of Path